# How to return multiple rows from mysql database with java

Tags: java, mysql

```
I want to select multiple rows and return them in an Arraylist.
```

My Database structure looks like this:

```
1   Bestellnummer   int(20)     
2   BestellerID int(20)         
3   ArtikelNummer   int(20)         
4   Anzahl  int(10)         
5   Preis   double
```

It doesnt have a unique key, since it will not be changed. 
I wrote this Method but i get the error:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BestellerID,ArtikelNummer,Preis FROM bestellungen WHERE
>   Bestellnummer = 1' at line 1Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out-of-bounds for length
>   0"

```
public ArrayList<Bestellung> getBestellung (int i) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Bestellung> Auftrag = new ArrayList<>();
        final String SQL ="SELECT*  BestellerID,ArtikelNummer,Preis FROM bestellungen WHERE Bestellnummer = ?" ;

        ResultSet rs = null ;
        try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setInt(1, i);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("test");

        while (rs.next()) {     
            Bestellung test = new Bestellung( i,  rs.getInt("BestellerID"), rs.getInt("ArtikelNummer"), rs.getDouble("Preis"));
            Auftrag.add(test);

        }
        }
         catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
         finally {
             if (rs!=null) {rs.close();
            }
         }
        return Auftrag;
                    }
}
public class Bestellung {
private int Bestellnummer, BestellerID,ArtikelNummer,Anzahl;
private double Preis;
```

Here is the Class that Objects will be in the Arraylist:

```
Bestellung (int Bestellnummerin,int BestellerIDin,int ArtikelNummerin,double Preisin)
{ 
this.Bestellnummer = Bestellnummerin ;
this.BestellerID = BestellerIDin ;
this.ArtikelNummer = ArtikelNummerin;
this.Anzahl = 1;
this.Preis = Preisin;
}}
```

Comment: Typo.  You have an errant `*` character in your SQL query.  Remove it.  For future note, any time MySQL (and many other systems) direct you to where a syntax error is, the problem is usually *immediately before that* because that's the point at which the parser could no longer parse the syntax.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832694/how-to-retrieve-multiple-row-from-database-in-java

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
final String SQL ="SELECT BestellerID,ArtikelNummer,Preis 
                  FROM bestellungen WHERE Bestellnummer = ?";
```

Comment: Usually people add explanation of their code in their answers. Anyway, the question's comments already contain the answer.